# Javascript onbeforeunload- Show an image on Exit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following code so that if user closes the browser button it shows a confirmation box, whether to stay on page or not.

What I want to do is if someone closes the browser it should show an image, with "yes" or "no" options. When "yes" is clicked it should close the browser and if "no" is clicked it shouldn't close the browser. The Image has to be shown in the same window not in any popup. Is it possible to do it or am I expecting too much from JavaScript?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var exit=true;
    function confirmExit()
            {
            if(exit)
            {
            window.location.href = "?p=exit";
            }
            if(exit)
            return "Wait! Don't Leave Empty Handed!\n\nThank you for taking the time to check out our offer! Before you go we have a complimentary crash to help you succeed. Click the 'Cancel' or 'Stay On This Page' button if you're interested!";
            }
</script>
</head>
<body  onbeforeunload="return confirmExit()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible

Comment: Would'nt that be just great for spammers and advertisers, if they could just stop you from leaving a page and keep on showing you images instead, while you where desperately clicking the close button?

Comment: The reason why you can not do it is exactly to block what you are trying to do. :)

Comment: *Thankfully*, this is impossible. Why would you want to do something so horrible to your users? When they want to leave your website, 99% of the time, this isn't by accident. They don't need some annoying  spammy thing trying to prevent them from leaving.

Comment: ALL i want to show it show some Exit message to user saying You will get 10% discount with a product code so what is the problem here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the `onbeforeunload()` default behaviour as it is native to each browser. You can only return a custom string.

Comment: Is it possible using JQuery ?

Comment: Jquery is javascript so its not possible

Answer (score 1):

This is really annoying, and I would advise against it.  However, you can display whatever you want if you create a popup using `window.open`.  Popup blockers are likely to block that, though.  In that case, you can return a string from the `onbeforeunload` callback that gets popped up, but it is handled per-browser (i.e. Firefox will print their own string, not the one you send back).

I reiterate, unless the client is doing some potentially important processing, I would not do anything to stop someone from closing their browser or otherwise navigating away.